# How can I fix this short test code in Python?

Tags: python, testing, odoo, odoo-10

> I am getting the following error in my code

```
2017-04-08 08:36:24,330 1467 INFO demo odoo.modules.module: odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo running tests.
2017-04-08 08:36:24,331 1467 INFO demo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: test_create (odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo.TestTodo)
2017-04-08 08:36:24,333 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: ERROR
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 INFO odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: ======================================================================
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: ERROR: test_create (odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo.TestTodo)
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `   File "/home/odoo/odoo-dev/custom-addons/todo_app/tests/test_todo.py", line 8, in test_create
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `     Todo = self.env['todo.task']
2017-04-08 08:36:24,334 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `   File "/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 752, in __getitem__
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `     return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `   File "/home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 170, in __getitem__
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: `     return self.models[model_name]
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: ` KeyError: 'todo.task'
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 INFO odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: Ran 1 test in 0.003s
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo: FAILED
2017-04-08 08:36:24,335 1467 INFO odoo odoo.addons.todo_app.tests.test_todo:  (errors=1)
2017-04-08 08:36:24,336 1467 ERROR odoo odoo.modules.module: Module todo_app: 0 failures, 1 errors
```

> Here is the snippet of my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
from odoo.tests.common import TransactionCase

class TestTodo(TransactionCase):

  def test_create(self):
    "Create a simple Todo"
    Todo = self.env['todo.task']
    task = Todo.create({'name': 'Test Task'})
    self.assertEqual(task.is_done, False)
```

> Can somebody please explain how to fix this please? Thanks a lot and
>   have a great day :D First question ever :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Error dumps aren't helpful or fun to read. Please post the code that might have caused the error instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
KeyError: 'todo.task'
```

this means that you don't have a todo.task model installed in you dabase
check if there is a table name todo_task in your database.

one of the thing that you missed may be you didn't import the Model in the `__init__.py` this why odoo didn't install it.